# Как открыть сокет для отправки tcp пакета python

Tags: python, ubuntu, сокет, tcp

Мне нужно ручками собрать tcp пакет (SYN) и отправить его на сервер. Как правильно открыть сокет чтобы не пришлось собирать пакеты на более низких уровнях. Пишу на ubuntu 18.04

открываю так, но не уверен что правильно:
`s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поставь [scapy](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html)

```
ip=IP(src="192.168.0.2",dst="192.168.0.1")  
SYN=TCP(sport=40508,dport=40508,flags="S",seq=12345)
send(ip/SYN)
```

простой конструктор пакетов, да и отправляет одной командой. [Готовый SYN сканер](https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#syn-scans)

Answer (score 0):

Помог ответ eri, можно заглянуть в документацию и помогла эта статья
https://medium.com/@NickKaramoff/tcp-packets-from-scratch-in-python-3a63f0cd59fe